# Distribution distance ; Riemann Geometry; Information Geometry

Tags: probability-distributions, riemannian-geometry, pythagorean-triples, information-geometry

[image]

As the upper image shows, $M_1$ is a distribution whose parameter is θ, while $M_2$ corresponds to $θ'=θ-δg$. $δ$ means learning rate and $g$ means the gradient. $M_2$ is optimised from $M_1$ by gradient descent. $M^*$ is a given truely model and $M_1$ $M_2$ are used to fit the $M^*$. All of the distribution distance between these models ($a b c$) are constructed by KL divergence. What I want to know is whether exists $\hat{M}$ with parameter $\hat{θ}=θ-αδg$ ($α $ is the variable) could form an orthogonal relationship about $M^*$ to get a less distribution distance than $KL(M_2 || M^*)$ and at the same time onto the line between $M_1$ $M_2$.

Comment: What do distributions have to do with this question? It looks like a pure Euclidean geometry question.

Comment: @LeeMosher the distribution distance is computed by the total variance, but the total variance is defined as L1 norm rather than L2 norm(Euclidean distance), so I doubt that whether it can form as a triangle in Euclidean space and solve this question by Pythagorean theorem. The aim for this question is to find a \hat{M}, and the line in the upper image maybe means high-dimensional curves ? (ps: I'm not sure)

Comment: In that case you need to precisely define the terminology in your post, and you need to precisely define the various quantities, or else it's just too unclear to be answerable. If you're not sure, neither are we.

Comment: M1 is a distribution whose parameter is θ, while M2 corresponds to θ'=θ-δg. δ means learning rate and g means the gradient. M2 is optimised from M1 by gradient descent. M* is a given truely model and M1 M2 are used to fit the M*. All of the distribution distance between these models (a b c) are constructed by KL divergence. What I want to know is whether exists \hat{M} with parameter \hat{θ}=θ-αδg (α is the variable) could form an orthogonal relationship about M* to get a less distribution distance than KL(M2 || M*). @LeeMosher

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,x\,$ be the distance from m2 to m^.

\begin{align*}
c^2-(a-x)^2&=b^2-x^2\\
c^2&=(a^2-2ax-x^2)+b^2-x^2\\
2ax&=a^2+b^2-c^2\\
x&=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2a}
\end{align*}

Let d be the distance from m* to m^
$$d=\sqrt{b^2-x^2}=\sqrt{b^2-\bigg(\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2a}\bigg)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your detail ! However, the key point in this question is not how to use the Pythagorean theorem to solve, what I pay more attention to is whether the usage of Pythagorean theorem is suitable in here, as I think the distribution distance is not defined by the Euclidean distance

Comment: @11   I really do not understand what distribution distance is about. However, as in quantum mechanics, once observed, probability switches to certainty and, in that case, the Pythagorean Theorem gives you the "then" distance in the observation.

Comment: Sry, I'm not familiar with quantum mechanics, but I'd like to interpret the concept of distribution distance. Like TV(total variance)(P || Q), where P and Q is probability distribution,  can be seen as the sum of the L1 norm for all the sample within the P and Q  scope (the exact definition for TV need multiple a constant 1/2).